# gSheets - Join two, different row size tabs (sheets) based on common key (date)

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

**Issue**: I am looking for a way to **join two datasheets in a gSheet file**. I have Date, Impressions, Clicks in one, and 3 different conversion types in the other (with Date included). The two sheets are different in length (one date is not only in one row). I would like to create a "master" sheet with Date, Impressions, Clicks and all the conversion types, where each date is there only once. If there are no data for a certain date from any of the sheets, that can be left empty. If there are no data from both sheets, the date can even be skipped, doesn't matter for me. The size of the ranges can vary wildly and there will be a lot of data (10k+ rows). I've tried to search for solutions (vlookup+arrayformula, query, etc.), but nothing suggested was working because of the different range sizes.

**Sample datasheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s5D9GI9cSQrc3Hpv8fOqw7c1Ae9UaX5N0IXO-OtF7GM/edit?usp=sharing**

**Background**: I am trying to build a marketing dashboard in gSheets to be imported to Data Studio. While Data Studio supports data blending (what I am looking for here), it doesn't support calculated metrics in blended data. So I am planning to create a Google Sheet with the "blended" data + all the metrics, and import that to Data Studio.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: In your test sheets you have 503 rows for 28/10/01 in one sheet and 62 rows for same date the other sheet. How do you propose to join these? You mean to sum all data in both sheets for a given date before joining the rows?

Comment: @bcperth yes, that is exactly what I mean! This difference will stay since the data will be split by campaign/ad group and there are more ad groups then conversion types, so there will be always more rows for a given data in the first sheet

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need to use a different formula for each column.  The first one lists all the Unique values from the first Sheet, which your sample calls "Adwords Data"  The formula looks like this:

The rest just use the Arrayformula function with sumif to sum the totals for each date.  Placing this in the second row, so you can have a header row is one way to do that.  For Impressions this becomes:

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A > 0;sumif('AdWords Data'!A2:A;A2:A;'AdWords Data'!B2:B);))
```

The arrayformula() function allows us to apply the rest to every row in the sheet.  Inside that we start with an IF() which is used to keep from putting values in rows that do not have dates. NOTE the difference from Excel where the last part of the IF() function has no value, and especially does not have "" which will actually place a value in the cell.  This is not a typo so please do not add the quotes.  You will not see it but functions and any custom code you write will and it will drive you nuts trying to figure out why.  The IF() statement checks to see if column A has a value.  If it does, then apply the SUMIF() function.  Here we sum items from column B in the "Adwords Data" sheet IF the contents of column A in that same sheet match the contents of this sheet's column A.  Adding new data will automatically expand the values reported in here.

To keep that from being edited, put it in the Header row and for a header in the first row by making a change to this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A1:A)=ROW(A1);"Impressions";if(A1:A > 0;sumif('AdWords Data'!A1:A;A1:A;'AdWords Data'!B1:B);)))
```

This starts with an IF statement that checks to see what Row the arrayformula is working on.  If it is the first row, it places "Impressions" for the Header.  If it is any other row it applies the IF() function from above.

I put all the formulas in your sample file in a sheet called "KS Sample" with the second version in column H.

If I misunderstood you, I apologize.  If this is the case, could you please make a sample sheet of what you expect the results to look like?

Regards,
Karl S